# Using TimeStamp with MySQL, it returns server time instead of local time

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a MySQL DB, somewhere not sure where it is physically, but I know the column in the table I'm requesting is a TimeStamp and I'm using AngularJS to filter the time like so: `{{dateVar | date:'h:mm a'}}`. When I get the time back it comes in 3 hours before my local time. My backend is in ExpressJS and it returns the time in this format `"2015-07-09T10:57:00.000Z"`. Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: why don't you store date time in UTC and while fetching data add your timezone to it.

Comment: Just convert it to your local time, if that's what you need to do.

Comment: How does your insert statement for this record look like?

Comment: How would I store it in UTC time? Is that DateTime? It is converting the time already but its converting to the wrong time like i think its coming in as server time then converting to something weird

Comment: I'm using Sequelize, but when It gets to the server its fine it saves as the server time but I was under the impression when the timestamp returns it will convert to the client local time

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why it wasn't returning the proper time, I was sending the server the client time and it was saving that time in the DB but what I should have been doing is saving the server time that way when it sends that time to the client it will do the conversion for you and display the proper time.